# Adding Sums in Python

Tags: python, sum

I have to make a code where user inputs numbers of which the sum will add up to 1001. But it can't go over that amount or it resets back to zero. The only issue I'm having is getting it so the code will print a "Congratulations" message when the user gets to 1001. This is my code so far.

I'm new to Python and would appreciate any help offered!

EDIT

So far I have this and it's working for adding the sums.

```
print ("Want to play a game? Add numbers until you reach 1001!")
print ("Current total is 0!")
total=0
while total < 1001:
    store=raw_input("Enter a number!") 
    num=int(store)
    total=total+num
    print total
print ("Congratulations! You won!")
```

The only problem I've having now is that the user can enter numbers over 1001 and still get the congratulations message.

should I put something like

```
if total > 1001: 
   print ("Oops! Too Far! Start Again!")
```

Comment: what is the reason for another `while` ?

Comment: `constant expression conditions` amazing!!!

Comment: Your current code will never leave the first loop as `while 1001>0` is always true. Also, the second while should really be an `if` - you don't want to endlessly print the message when sum is 1001.

Comment: @Jack - No, what you have now was an incorrect post I made a few minutes ago.  Sorry--I didn't read the question carefully.  My current post or Steve's post works the way you want.

Comment: @iCodez, I see that now. Thanks! Everything seems to be in working order now! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your while-loops will run forever since their conditions will always evaluate to `True` (actually, you will never even get to the second because the first will run forever).

Here is a fixed version of your script:

```
print "Want to play a game? Add numbers until you reach 1001!"
print "Current total is 0!"
# Don't name a variable `sum` -- it overrides the built-in
total = 0
# This will loop until `total` equals 1001
while total != 1001:
    store = raw_input("Enter a number!") 
    num = int(store)
    # This is the same as `total=total+num`
    total += num
    print total
    # If we have gone over 1001, reset `total` to 0
    if total > 1001:
        print "Oops! Too Far! Start Again!"
        total = 0
# When we get here, the total will be 1001
print "Congratulations! You won!"
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you have `while 1001 > 0`, which is **always true**, so you get an **infinite loop**.  Additionally, `while 1001 == sum` will also produce an **infinite loop**, considering that once you get there, you are never changing `sum`.  The following is a simplified and fixed version of your code:

```
#sum is a function, so name it something else,  I chose sum_ for simplicity's sake
while sum_ != 1001:
    #instead of using an intermediate, I just combined the two lines
    num=int(raw_input("Enter a number!"))

    #This is equivalent to sum = sum + num
    sum_ += num
    print sum_

    #Need to reset if sum_ goes above 1001
    if sum_ > 1001:
        sum_ = 0

#By the time you get here, you know that _sum is equal to 1001
print ("Congratulations! You won!")
```

Comment: I think there is a convention that the underscore should be placed _after_ the built-in name.  Can't remember the link though...

Comment: @iCodez You're correct, here's the [link](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Ctrl-F for "convention to avoid"